# What is the purpose of types/union in yaccs and lex?

Tags: yacc, lex

I'm learning yacc and lex with some tutorial code that builds a parser allowing you to do the following:
1. Assign integers to single letter variables
2. Do addition and subtraction using numbers and variables
3. Output the value of a variable

In the tutorial, it says to allow assignment of numbers to variables, we need the lex file to return two different kinds of values, which are then declared in a union in the yacc file.

I have no idea why this is even necessary. I've actually went ahead and changed the tutorial code so it works without using types/union and it works just fine (I merely just used the value of NAME to set the index in symtbl to the integer it is assigned to). So what I'm confused about is why even use types and the union? Below is the code from the tutorial.

```
%{
...

int symtbl[26];
bool issym[26];
%}

%union {
  int rvalue; /* value of evaluated expression */
  int lvalue; /* index into symtbl for variable name */
}

%token <rvalue> NUMBER
%token <lvalue> NAME 

%type <rvalue> expression
%type <rvalue> const

%%
statement_list : statement '\n'
      | statement_list statement '\n'
      ;

statement: NAME '=' expression { symtbl[$1] = $3; issym[$1] = true; }
      | expression  { printf("%d\n", $1); }
      ;

expression: expression '+' const { $$ = $1 + $3; }
      | expression '-' const { $$ = $1 - $3; }
      | const { $$ = $1; }
      ;

const: NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
     | NAME 
       { 
          if (issym[$1]) { $$ = symtbl[$1]; } 
          else { fprintf(stderr, "Error: variable %c not previously defined\n", $1+'a'); exit(1); }
       }
     ;
%%
```

So my question is why do we need the rvalue and lvalue types? Why put it in a union? Also why declare a rule as a specific type?

Comment: How would you handle variables whose names were longer than one character?

Comment: I've done some more digging and from what I understand, the union allows you to specify different types that yylval might be? So for a variable with more than one character, you'd specify a string type? If I'm not mistaken, this example is merely "faking" having variables by converting a letters a-z to 0-25. 
And if I actually wanted to have variables with longer names, I'd have to specify a new type, say var_name of type string, and return that type from the lexer?

Comment: That's the idea.

Comment: If I can ask one more thing to clarify. When do you need to specify the type of a rule? For example the rule 'statement' doesn't have a type declared on it. Do you only need to specify the type when you are passing the value up with '$$ = ' ?

Comment: You don't need to, it just helps to prevent you from committing mistakes. Same principle as types in a programming language. Grammars grow pretty large, and all help with keeping them clean and error-free is good.

Comment: @user2889046: you need to declare the type of a non-terminal's semantic value unless it doesn't have one. If it doesn't have a value you can't assign to `$$` in any production rule for that non-terminal, nor can you use the semantic value (`$n`) of that non-terminal appearing on the right-hand side of a rule.

Comment: Deleting answered questions isn't a great way to make yourself popular here. Just sayin